# Create new column of results from function counting days between two other columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to count the days between two dates stored in two columns but only count the days from may to august (growing season for trees) and populate a new column:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Start','End'],data=[[np.datetime64('2001-01-01'),np.datetime64('2001-07-01')],[np.datetime64('2001-01-01'),np.datetime64('2001-11-01')]])

def vegetation_days(date1, date2):
    startdate=date1.astype(datetime)
    enddate=date2.astype(datetime)
    all_dates = (startdate + datetime.timedelta(days=x) for x in range(0, (enddate-startdate).days))
    return (sum(1 for date in all_dates if (5 <= date.month <=7)))
```

Then:

```
df:

       Start        End
0 2001-01-01 2001-07-01
1 2001-01-01 2001-11-01

df['Days'] = vegetation_days(df['Start'],df['End'])
```

Which gives me error:

> AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'days'

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
def vegetation_days(date1, date2):
    all_dates = (date1 + pd.Timedelta(days=x) for x in range(0, (date2-date1).days))
    return (sum(1 for date in all_dates if (5 <= date.month <=7)))

df['Days'] = df.apply(lambda x: vegetation_days(x['Start'], x['End']), axis=1)
print (df)
       Start        End  Days
0 2001-01-01 2001-07-01    61
1 2001-01-01 2001-11-01    92
```